# Google Maps API Intel XDK Waypoints

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intel-xdk

For a school project I have to make an app, using Intel XDK, jQuery Mobile and an API. I wanted to make an app in which you can make a route and display this route on a google-maps-map (like a travelapp to view your trips).

I used Intel XDK (HTML5 + Cordova and the App Designer) and got an API key from the Google Maps Javascript API.

Right now, I have used the Google Maps API and displaying a route from A to B went well. In the following code (this is in my script) I tried to add waypoints to my route. In my HTML code I have three text-inputs for the user (start, via (=waypoint), end), the map and a button to show the route. I have looked at many sample codes, but my code doesn't work and I don't know why. There is no error, but if you push the showbutton, nothing happens. What have I done wrong or what did I miss?

I hope anyone can help and thanks in advance!

```
 var directionDisplay;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    // set direction render options
    //var rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    // add the map to the map placeholder
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
}

 function calcRoute() {
    var start = $('#start-input').val();
    var via = $('#via-input').val();
    var end = $('#end-input').val();
    var waypts = [];

    waypts.push({
        location: via,
        stopover: true
    });

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status); 
        }
    });
}

 function createMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
 }

 /* button  #show-btn */
$(document).on("click", "#show-btn", function(evt) {
    initMap();
    createMarker(start);
    createMarker(via);
    createMarker(end);

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the variables `start`, `via` and `end` as local variables in your `calcRoute` function, meaning they're not available to any code outside of that function.  So when you try and refer to them in these lines, they'll be undefined, and I suspect you're getting a JS error:

```
createMarker(start);
createMarker(via);
createMarker(end);
```

Make them global variables instead; define them at the same time as you do this:

```
 var directionDisplay;
```

i.e. that becomes:

```
 var directionDisplay, start, via, end;
```

And then remove the `var` keyword from where you refer to them in the `calcRoute` function, i.e. do:

```
 function calcRoute() {
    start = $('#start-input').val();
    via = $('#via-input').val();
    end = $('#end-input').val();
```

You also have the same problem with your `map` variable.  You create that as a local variable in your `initMap` function, and then try and refer to it in the `createMarker` function, which won't have access to it.  Make that a global variable too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't change anything. It still doesn't do anything..

Comment: Add some `console.log()` to each function to find out how far it's getting.  What do the values for `start`, `end` and `via` all look like?

Comment: Possibly because of the same problem with your `map` - see my updated answer.